# Make a subclass property transient

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a class A which is extended by a subclass B.
What is the best way to make one of the properties that B inherit from A transient and not persisted for class B?

When using hbm xml for configuration, transient fields are not indicated in any way and are just omitted from the xml, unlike when using annotations and the @Transient annotation.

Is this a valid solution to make x transient and not persisted for B?

```
public class A{    
  private Long x;
  private Long y;    

  public Long getX() {return x;}
  public Long getY() {return y;}
}

public class B extends A{    
  private Long z; 
  private transient Long x; 

  public Long getZ() {return z;}
  public Long getX() {return x;}
}
```

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052717/hibernate-override-transient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using XML configuration, you can take advantage of `insert="false"` and `update="false"` attributes:

```xml
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="name.of.thepackage.containing.B" table="b">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="id" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="z" type="java.lang.Long" />
        <property name="x" type="java.lang.Long" insert="false" update="false" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

These attributes means that the field won't be used nor in `INSERT` nor in `UPDATE` SQL statements.